# Find a example of $A$ be $4 \times 4$ matrix such that $A$ has rank $2$ but $A^2 =0 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, nilpotence

Find a   example  of  $A$ be $4 \times 4$ matrix    such that  $A$  has  rank $2$  but $A^2 =0 $?

My attempt :

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 &0\\0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 &0 &0 &0 \\0 &0 &0 &0 \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Is  it  correct ??

Any hints/solution will be apprecaited

thanks u

Comment: Your example has rank $1$. You might be better off considering the Jordan canonical form.

Comment: Along the right lines, but looks like rank $1$ to me ...

Comment: Ya  ,that is my  misunderstanding  @ Mark  and @EuYu

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean to find an **example** (rather than a counterexample) of a 4-by-4 matrix $A$ such that $A$ has rank 2 but $A^2=0$?

Comment: @user1551 ok i will edits

Comment: One way of thinking about the rank is as the dimension of the image space of a linear map. The image here will be a subspace $W$ of four dimensional space $V$ - because you want $A^2=0$ you end up applying $A$ to $W$ and getting zero. (I'm using terms loosely here). Rank $2$ means that the rank-nullity theorem tells you that $W$ has dimension $2$. Pick a convenient two dimensional subspace $W$ to go to zero, and then make sure you map everything in $V$ to $W$ and that both basis vectors in $W$ appear in the image of $V$. It is this last bit which didn't work for your first attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first 2 lines are not independent thus the rank is 1 and not 2.
Look at
 $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 &0\\0  & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 &0 &0 &0 \\0 &1 &0 &0 \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks   @J. Doe  this matrix  didn't came in my mind